# How to launch the browsers through the XML parameters

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am experiencing difficulties with launching the browser using TestNG parameters

I am experiencing difficulties with launching the browser using TestNG parameters however when i tried to change the value of the paramter from XML file always run with chrome and if i tried to remove the @Optional i get an error "Parameter 'browser' is required by BeforeSuite on method startDriver but has not been marked @Optional or defined"

here's my code for TestBase:

```java
@BeforeSuite
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void startDriver(@Optional("chrome") String browserName) {
            if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
                // Set the path to the Chrome driver
                System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_SILENT_OUTPUT_PROPERTY, "true");
                System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");

                // insecure connection / untrusted certificate
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
                driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
                options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
                options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
                options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
                options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");


            } else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("headless")) {
                System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_SILENT_OUTPUT_PROPERTY, "true");
                System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");

                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
                options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
                options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
                options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
                options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
                options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
                options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
                options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
                options.addArguments("--headless");
                driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            }else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid browser parameter value: " + browserName);
            }
```

And here's my XML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Regression Suite" parallel="none">

    <test name="Regression Test" preserve-order="true">

        <parameter name="browser" value="headless"/>

        <classes>
            <class name="org.TestCasesWithoutItems.ApplicationContentTestCase"> </class>

        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove @Optional annotation and define the parameter in the XML file:
Remove the @Optional annotation from the startDriver method, and make sure the browser parameter is defined in the XML file. Update your XML file as follows:

```
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Regression Suite" parallel="none">
    <test name="Regression Test" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="org.TestCasesWithoutItems.ApplicationContentTestCase"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: I tried to remove the Optional annotation  and I used the XML file you add but I got this error: 
"Parameter 'browser' is required by BeforeSuite on method startDriver but has not been marked @Optional or defined"

Comment: @Haiderwaleed - Please ensure that the parameter `<parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>` is defined outside the `<test>` tag.